# SSD and VMware's Excessive Disk Writes

Tags: virtual-machine, ssd, vmware

After my older SSD was dead I installed a new Corsair Neutron SSD.

I want to use multiple virtual machines as my development environments. But I fear my SSD will be dead very early because of VMware's excessive disk writes.

Here is a screen capture of the disk usage:

[image]

What do you think? Is there a configuration that can reduce disk writes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the optimizations for host OS applies to virtual machine guest OS, so;

1. Turn off disk defragmentation scheduling
2. Turn off search indexing
3. Align partition (to a multiple of 4kb = 4096 bytes)
4. Turn off hibernation??? (saves space, found this from a Corsair document)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to save on SSD writes, store it all in a RAMdisk and save/restore the content of that RAMdisk at boot/logoff.

However I see no need to do this just to write less to an SSD. A modern SSD (as in, not the ones from the first year or two that SSDs were on the market) should be just fine with heavy writes for quite a few years. And after 5 to 10 years most of us replace it anyway with something newer and shinier.

Comment: They use of a RAMDisk is the best approach here even with a durable SSD.